# What does it mean for the fundamental group of the n-leafed rose $C_{n}$ to be free of rank $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, knot-theory

The derivation from "introduction to knot theory" Richard H. Crowell is given below:

> > [image]
> >
> > [image]
> >
> > [image]

[image]
[image]

**My questions are:**

1-What does it mean for the fundamental group of the n-leafed rose $C_{n}$ to be free of rank $n$?

2-Why if a group is infinite cyclic, it is called free group of rank 1?
3- Why we consider The open neighborhood of p to consist of $2(n + 1)$ disjoint, open arcs, why specifically $2(n+1)$, is it because each leaf can be divided into 2 arcs?

4-why in figure 23, part of it is drawn dotted?

Could anyone help me in answering these questions please?

**EDIT:**

> > [image]

Comment: "Free of rank $n$" is a particular kind of group.  Look up free groups.  And when the rank is $1$, it's iso to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: is n the number of elements in its generator? ....... how through the previous proof they arrived at this result .....what do we reach at the end of the proof that make us say that this is the fundamental group?@Randall

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the number of generators.

Comment: If you're looking for help on the proof, we will need to know what 3.3 is.

Comment: He says in the proof that it follows from (3.3) immediately, whatever that is.

Comment: oh @rogerl beat me to it by 22 seconds.

Comment: @rogerl   Sorry I will add it it is a consequence of Van Kampen

Comment: Sorry I will add it it is a consequence of Van Kampen  @Randall

Comment: So now the question is: Do you understand the statement of Van Kampen's Theorem, and how that statement is being applied in this situation? And if not, is there a particular mathematical point that is confusing to you, about either the statement or the application?

Comment: @LeeMosher  Frankly speaking I am trying to understand it and its application until now ..... it is difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'll say that an essential prerequisite to this question is knowledge of free groups. Granted, many people's first experience with free groups arises when they first encounter Van Kampen's Theorem. Nonetheless, what one should do at that point is to set aside Van Kampen's Theorem and learn about free groups. The essential features are this:

- Given a group $G$, a subset $S \subset G$ is a *free basis* of $G$ if for any group $H$ and any function $f : S \to H$, there exists a unique homomorphism $F : G \to H$ such that $f = F \mid S$.
- A group is free if it has a free basis.
- If a group is free than all of its free bases have the same cardinality, and that number is called the *rank* of the free group.

There are further very important features regarding uniqueness of a [reduced word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(group_theory)#Reduced_words) in the elements of $S$ and their inverses for each element of $G$, but that is not essential for this problem.

To answer your question 1, the statement of the theorem being proved in this passage of Crowell is that $\pi_1(C_{(n)})$ is a free group of rank $n$ and $\{\omega_1 x_1,...,\omega_n x_n\}$ is a free basis.

To answer your question 2, in the group $\mathbb Z$ the set $\{1\}$ is a free basis, as one can easily prove. Therefore $\mathbb Z$ is a rank $1$ free group. Every infinite cyclic group is therefore a rank $1$ free group: a group is infinite cyclic if and only if it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$; and the property that a group is "free of rank $n$" is an isomorphism invariant.

To answer your questions 3 and 4, as one can see from reading the statement of Van Kampen's Theorem, open subsets play an important role. The difference between dotted and undotted lines is meant to emphasize issues explained in the text that you pasted in, regarding various subsets of $C_{(n+1)}$ that are and are not open; this is needed for purposes of applying Van Kampen's Theorem. The solid lines are meant to represent an open subset containing $p$ which is denoted $N$; you can see this from the diagram, by observing the pointers from the letter $N$ to various portions of that open subset. The dotted lines are meant to represent the complement of $N$.

Answer (score 2):

1) It is the free group on $n$ generators $F_n = \langle g_1,\dots,g_n  \mid \; \rangle$, where each generator $g_i$ is given by the homotopy class of the loop going around $X_i$. I can give you concrete representatives of the isomorphism class of $F_n$ for some given $n$, namely for example the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ for $n =1$ or $\langle a,b \rangle \subset \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, where $$a = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \;\; b = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ for $n =2$. Otherwise it is just some abstract group satisfying some universal property or you can construct some representative in the way that Rylee said in the comment.

One usually proves that fact by using the Seifert van Kampen theorem which is probably related to some of the statements the author is quoting.

2) See 1).

3) Yes exactly. Each of the circles has two arcs starting at $p$.

4) I guess to visualize that we excluded the dotted part when we took the neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: This is only a quibble about 1). Using the fact that $F_2$ contains free subgroups of every at-most countable rank and the representation as a group of matrices you've given, you can construct concrete representatives of $F_n$ as a group of matrices for every $n$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Did not think of that. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to consider this, cf [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf) (T&G), or [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html). Define the fundamental groupoid $G= \pi_1(X,S)$ on a **set** $S$ of base points. For example, let $X$ be the interval $[0,n]$ and let $S$ be the set $\{0,1,\ldots, n\}$. Since $[0,n]$ is convex, the groupoid $G$ has  then $n+1$ objects, and exactly one arrow say $\tau_{ij}:j \to i $.  This is a rather easy kind of *free groupoid*, called a    *tree groupoid* in T&G. Note that $\tau_{ij}\tau_{jk}=\tau_{ik}$.

$$  i \xrightarrow{\tau_{ij}}j \xrightarrow{\tau_{jk}} k $$

Now if you identify all the points of $S$ to a single point $p$, then  the space $X$ becomes the $n$-leaf rose. and its fundamental group at the point $p$ is the free group on the images of the $\tau_{i,i+1}: i \to i+1$ for $i=0, \ldots, n-1$.  You then need a version of the van Kampen Theorem for the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points to get  the expected result, and of course many more.

Compare [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) mathoverflow discussion.

:

Comment: Fixed a problem with the first two links.